# MailChimp. Error 401 (Unauthorized) when sending a request for adding a new list member

Tags: javascript, request, fetch, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Here is how I'm trying to send a request:

```
fetch('https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/185415c92c/members', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'anystring:8ec49e64f2041073d3fe56e0abc5fe5f-us17',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email_address: 'email@mail.ru',
        status: 'subscribed',
      }),
      mode: 'no-cors',
    })
```

And I get such error:

`POST https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/185415c92c/members 401 (Unauthorized)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 401 shows your `Authorization` header is probably invalid

Comment: but what should be there?

Comment: Is that really your API key after `anystring:`?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell yes

Comment: Here is a website where you can test it http://silencer.website/stasyq/

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the requested resource?

Comment: Yes, I tried to test it with postman and it works, but I don't know why it doesn't work on my website:

http://prntscr.com/ihr3g9
http://prntscr.com/ihr38b
http://prntscr.com/ihr3nt

Comment: nope, doesn't work =(

Answer (score 0):

The `Authorization` header contains both type and credentials, but in your code the header only contains the latter. The following should work:

`Authorization: Basic <base64-encoding of anystring:8ec49e64f2041073d3fe56e0abc5fe5f-us17>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

EDIT: The real reason why it wasn't working: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which MailChimp understandably doesn't support.

Answer (score -1):

I kept having the same issue, I checked my Key from MailChimp in my account setting. Under KEY, it said my key  "was disabled" and under LABEL it said "posted in public, do not enable". Sometimes it's not our code, it's the key itself.  Try checking the key you are currently using.